# How do I assign images to image nodes using script?

Tags: materials, scripting, node-editor, shader-nodes

```
# Corrected version
import bpy

#list of plants in minecraft
PlantsMaterials = ['leaves', 'cornflower','tall_grass','seagrass','lily_pad','carrots','beetroots',
'cave_vines','dead_bush','fern','big_dripleaf','potatoes','moss_carpet','saplings','small_dripleaf','spore_blossom',
'sugar_cane','sweet_berry_bush','vines','wheat','dandelion','poppy','blue_orchid','azure_bluet','tulip','oxeye_daisy',
'lily_of_the_valley','wither_rose','sunflower','lilac','peony']

#make shader for leaves
for plantlist in PlantsMaterials:
    for material in bpy.data.materials:
        if plantlist in material.name:
            nodes = material.node_tree.nodes
            links = material.node_tree.links

            #clear links and nodes
            nodes.clear()
            links.clear()
            
            #add nodes
            imgtex = nodes.new(type='ShaderNodeTexImage')
            princi = nodes.new(type='ShaderNodeBsdfPrincipled')
            output = nodes.new(type='ShaderNodeOutputMaterial')
            hueSa1 = nodes.new(type='ShaderNodeHueSaturation')
            hueSa2 = nodes.new(type='ShaderNodeHueSaturation')
            trnslu = nodes.new(type='ShaderNodeBsdfTranslucent')
            colRam = nodes.new(type='ShaderNodeValToRGB')
            mapran = nodes.new(type='ShaderNodeMapRange')
            addsha = nodes.new(type='ShaderNodeAddShader')

            #link all nodes
            links.new(princi.outputs[0], addsha.inputs[1])
            links.new(addsha.outputs[0], output.inputs[0])
            links.new(trnslu.outputs[0], addsha.inputs[0])
            links.new(hueSa1.outputs[0], trnslu.inputs[0])
            links.new(hueSa2.outputs[0], hueSa1.inputs[4])
            links.new(hueSa2.outputs[0], princi.inputs[0])
            links.new(mapran.outputs[0], princi.inputs[9])
            links.new(colRam.outputs[0], mapran.inputs[0])

            #assign values for nodes
            princi.inputs[7].default_value = 0.1
            hueSa1.inputs[2].default_value = 0.9
            hueSa2.inputs[2].default_value = 0.9
            mapran.inputs[3].default_value = 0.2
            mapran.inputs[4].default_value = 0.7
            colRam.color_ramp.interpolation = 'CARDINAL'
            colRam.color_ramp.elements[0].position = 0.03
            colRam.color_ramp.elements[1].position = 0.2
            colRam.color_ramp.elements[1].color = (0.801,0.87,0.87,1)
            
            #assign different iamges for each materials in the list
            plantname = material.name + ".png"
            print(plantname)
            realplantname = plantname.replace("minecraft_block-","")
            print(realplantname)
            tex = bpy.data.images.get(realplantname)
            imgtex.image = tex
                
            #link images to rest of the nodes
            links.new(imgtex.outputs[1], princi.inputs[21])
            links.new(imgtex.outputs[0], hueSa2.inputs[4])
            links.new(imgtex.outputs[0], colRam.inputs[0])
```

Everything works thanks to the person who replied my question yesterday, but
"#assign different iamges for each materials in the list" part doesn't work.

```
#assign different iamges for each materials in the list
plantname = material.name + ".png"
print(plantname)
realplantname = plantname.replace("minecraft_block-","")
print(realplantname)
tex = bpy.data.images.get(realplantname)
imgtex.image = tex
```

images are not being added to the image nodes.
Even if I type very specific image like

```
tex = bpy.data.images.get('birch.png')
```

instead of variable. It would be great if someone could help me.

Comment: `imgtex.image = bpy.data.images[realplantname]` should work.  If it doesn't, you should be getting an error message either in the Info window or on the system (not Python) console.  What is happening? Perhaps your code to construct the `realplantname` isn't creating the right value?  Aside: if you found my answer useful yesterday, please read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) and perhaps upvote or accept my answer

Comment: You're probably looking for `bpy.data.images.load('birch.png', check_existing=True)`, which creates an image if it hasn't been loaded yet. But just `birch.png` doesn't tell you what folder it's in, so you should use either the full path (starting with C:\ or whatever) or a [relative path](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.79/data_system/files/relative_paths.html).

Comment: @MartyFouts "imgtex.image = bpy.data.images[realplantname]" seems to have solved the problem. now everything works fine! thanks! and I also accepted your answer :)

Comment: @scurest thanks for your help!